# Adding a new class to HTML tag and writing it back with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, html5, beautifulsoup

I am working on an HTML document to which I need to add certain classes to some elements. In the following code, I am adding class `img-responsive`.

```
def add_img_class1(img_tag):
    try:
        img_tag['class'] = img_tag['class']+' img-responsive'   
    except KeyError:
        img_tag['class'] = 'img-responsive'
    return img_tag

def add_img_class2(img_tag):
    if img_tag.has_attr('class'):
        img_tag['class'] = img_tag['class']+' img-responsive'
    else:
        img_tag['class'] = 'img-responsive'
    return img_tag

soup = BeautifulSoup(myhtml)
for img_tag in soup.find_all('img'):    
    img_tag = add_img_class1(img_tag) #or img_tag = add_img_class2(img_tag)


html = soup.prettify(soup.original_encoding)
with open("edited.html","wb") as file:
    file.write(html)
```

1. Both functions do same, however one uses exceptions and another has_attr from BS4. Which is better and why?
2. Am I doing the right way of writing back to HTML? Or shall convert entire soup to UTF-8 (by `string.encode('UTF-8')`) and write it?

Answer (score 14):

The second option is better, because the possible error is explicit. However, in lots of case in Python, you should follow [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) and go for the `try` statement. However, we can do better.

### get(value, default)

In BeautifulSoup, attributes behave like dictionaries. This means you can write `img_tag.get('class', '')` to get the class if it exists, or the empty string if it doesn't.

```
def add_img_class(img_tag):
    img_tag = img_tag.get('class', '') + ' img-responsive'
```

You don't need to return the new `img_tag` as it is passed by reference. Now that your function is a one-liner, you might as well use the one-liner directly.

### Multi-valued attributes

Note that the above code doesn't work! `class` is a multi-valued attribute in HTML4 and HTML5, so at least BeautifulSoup 4 returns a list instead of a string. The correct code becomes:

```
img_tag['class'] = img_tag.get('class', []) + ['img-responsive']
```

Wich is nicer as you don't have to worry about the extra space between the two values.

### Encoding

You don't need to convert to UTF-8 before writing the file back. What's wrong with `&nbsp;`?

Comment: Using `img['class'] = img.get('class', []) + ['img-responsive']`
results in *TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found* but `img['class'] = img.get('class', []) + ' img-responsive` does the trick.

Comment: FredCampos, did you use BeautifulSoup4? Did you parse your document as HTML? The BeautifulSoup 4 docs mentions that `img[class]` should always return a list: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#multi-valued-attributes